# excel and access integration

Tags: excel, vba

I have my front end in excel and backend as access. I send these files to client everyday.i do not want others to see the database. Is there a way to integrate access in excel such that if i transfer only excel file, access file also gets transferred automatically and others do not get to know about my database??
database should remain in access only.

Comment: why do you need to transfer your database with the file? Can you set up the XL file in such a way that it has everything you would need from access in it?

Answer (score 0):

You can't email or FTP an Access file invisibly, but you could move your data to a SQL Server (or other) database that is reachable from the internet.
However that poses several issues:
1) security
2) odbc DSN
3) availability of the odbc driver on the client machine

Answer (score 0):

You can embed the Access database as an object into your Excel file (`Insert->Object->Create from file` , select `Display as icon`) and ask the user to extract and remove it. However, this is a bit cumbersome for both sides if you do it manually.

If you want to automate the process, use the following code:

```
Private Const cStrSheetName As String = "Sheet1"
Private Const cStrObjName As String = "EmbeddedFile"

Sub EmbedFile()
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Sheets(cStrSheetName)

    strFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Any file (*.*), *.*", 1, _
        "Please select a file to embed")

    If strFile = "False" Then Exit Sub

    On Error Resume Next
    ws.Shapes(cStrObjName).Delete

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    ws.OLEObjects.Add(Filename:=strFile, Link:=False, _
        DisplayAsIcon:=True, IconFileName:="", _
        IconIndex:=0, IconLabel:=strFile).Select
    Selection.Name = cStrObjName

    MsgBox "File succesfully embedded!"

    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Could not embed file. Error: " & _
        Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description

End Sub

Sub ExtractEmbeddedFile()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Sheets(cStrSheetName)

    On Error Resume Next
    ws.OLEObjects(cStrObjName).Copy

    If Err.Number Then
        MsgBox "No file embedded!"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    CreateObject("Shell.Application").Namespace(ActiveWorkbook.Path) _
        .Self.InvokeVerb "Paste"

    If MsgBox("File succesfully extracted to " & ActiveWorkbook.Path _
        & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Do you want to remove the embedded " & _
        "file from the this workbook to reduce its size?", vbYesNo) _
        = vbYes Then
        ws.Shapes(cStrObjName).Delete
    End If

    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Error extracting file: " & _
        Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description

End Sub
```

This will give you two macros (`EmbedFile` and `ExtractEmbeddedFile`) that you can assign to a button in your worksheet.

Please note that you need to modify `"Sheet1"` in the first line to the name of the worksheet you want to store the embedded file.

Comment: it would be a great help if you could tell me how to extract and delete using vba.

Comment: Thanks a lot Peter..now how can i use embeded acess file in my excel vba?I mean is there any way to querry on the embeded mdb file without opening it using vba??

Comment: While the code probably can be expanded to relink any existing data connections to the extracted Access, I'm really not sure that this is the right approach. Do you know that you can apply SQL to Excel tables, too? So instead of storing (and handling?) the data in Access, just do this in Excel, too!